# Cucumber /Gherkin: Passing variables between different step definition

Tags: groovy, cucumber, rest-assured, gherkin

I am new to Cucumber and gherkin world. I wanted to know is there a good way of sharing variables across the different step definition files?
For my example: I have 2 feature files(GET and POST) and this has 2 step definition files(GET and POST). Both the feature file has a common step for test data set up . So I thought I will move this data set up to a CommonSteps file, which I was able to do. But in this data set up method, I am assigning a value to a variable, which needs to be consumed in the 2 step defintion files(GET and POST).My question is how can I accomplish this through  Gherkin?

Comment: Any help with this one ? I know there are Java dependency injection concept which can take care of this but I wanted to check if there is any better way to do through GHerkin.

Comment: The recommended way to share variables/objects between steps in java/jvm is through Dependency Injection. You can use one of several dependency frameworks. Afaik you cannot share it through Gherkin. In case you're using Spring, I've written a blog about using Spring with Java [here](https://medium.com/@mlvandijk/managing-state-in-cucumber-jvm-using-spring-a795e9a1dd18).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing state between steps defined in different step classes is as [@Marit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7121619/marit) says done using dependency injection.

Other flavors of Cucumber uses a shared World object. You can use a `public static` variable to share state, but it is troublesome as state may leak between steps. You may end up in a situation where steps start to depend on each other with a shared variable that isn't reset before every execution. Steps that depends on other steps are a well known problem withing the Cucumber community and something you want to avoid at all cost.

Cucumber supports a few different dependency injection frameworks. If your project already uses a dependency injection framework, see if you can use the same for your Cucumber scenarios. If  you don't use any dependency injection framework, I would suggest using PicoContainer.

I have written a few blog posts about some of the different options:

- [PicoContainer](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer)
- [Guice](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/08/16/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-guice)
- [Spring](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/06/24/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-spring)

They are all Java based. I assume that it will be possible to use them with Groovy, but I haven't tried.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. I ended up using public static and till now it works good, where the variable is being used across different step def files. But I'll definitely try to revisit this approach, given there are above mentioned side effects of using static variable. I didnt go with WorldObject because it sounded little bit complex to me.

Comment: A public static variable will work. Until it doesn't. Remember that it is not reset between executions and therefore risky. Most likely dangerous.